# Error when trying to deploy Django app to Heroku - Conflicting Dependencies

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip

This is the error i get when trying to push, everything was working fine a week ago, I could deploy with no problems. Now when I try to deploy I always get this error beacuse I can't satisfy both python-dateutil==2.8 (needed by the app) and python-dateutl==1.5 (needed by heroku).
No clue why this started happening. (Updated heroku globally but nothing changed).
There is a wrapper [Heroku3](https://pypi.org/project/heroku3/) but I can't seem to use it to deploy, when i install it in the env, heroku3 command doesn't exist and its not available on npm, so all I can do is write python code with it.
Would really appreciate if someone knew how to resolve this problem.

```
git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 401, done.
Counting objects: 100% (401/401), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (321/321), done.
Writing objects: 100% (386/386), 226.01 KiB | 4.43 MiB/s, done.
Total 386 (delta 39), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> No Python version was specified. Using the same version as the last build: python-3.9.7
remote:        To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
remote: -----> Using cached install of python-3.9.7
remote: -----> Installing pip 21.3.1, setuptools 57.5.0 and wheel 0.37.0
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of gunicorn to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==20.1.0
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-storages to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        Collecting django-storages==1.11.1
remote:          Downloading django_storages-1.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-heroku to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        Collecting django-heroku==0.3.1
remote:          Downloading django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-crispy-forms to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        Collecting django-crispy-forms==1.12.0
remote:          Downloading django_crispy_forms-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (122 kB)
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        Collecting Django==3.2.7
remote:          Downloading Django-3.2.7-py3-none-any.whl (7.9 MB)
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of dj-database-url to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        Collecting dj-database-url==0.5.0
remote:          Downloading dj_database_url-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.5 kB)
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of charset-normalizer to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        Collecting charset-normalizer==2.0.4
remote:          Downloading charset_normalizer-2.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of certifi to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        Collecting certifi==2021.5.30
remote:          Downloading certifi-2021.5.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of botocore to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        Collecting botocore==1.21.39
remote:          Downloading botocore-1.21.39-py3-none-any.whl (7.9 MB)
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of <Python from Requires-Python> to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.       
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of boto3 to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        Collecting boto3==1.18.39
remote:          Downloading boto3-1.18.39-py3-none-any.whl (131 kB)
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of beautifulsoup4 to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
remote:          Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.9.3-py3-none-any.whl (115 kB)
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of asgiref to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        Collecting asgiref==3.4.1
remote:          Downloading asgiref-3.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of botocore to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        ERROR: Cannot install -r /tmp/build_414b410f/requirements.txt (line 4), heroku==0.1.4 and python-dateutil==2.8.2 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
remote:
remote:        The conflict is caused by:
remote:            The user requested python-dateutil==2.8.2
remote:            botocore 1.21.39 depends on python-dateutil<3.0.0 and >=2.1
remote:
remote:        To fix this you could try to:
remote:        1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
remote:        2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
remote:
remote:        ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 37f55b221f93a23b73486ebf55520365c1b5bcb8
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 37f55b221f93a23b73486ebf55520365c1b5bcb8
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to app.
remote:
To gitlink
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'gitlink'
```

When i do pip freeze I get this

```
asgiref==3.4.1
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3    
boto3==1.18.39
botocore==1.21.39        
certifi==2021.5.30       
charset-normalizer==2.0.4
click==8.0.1
colorama==0.4.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0   
Django==3.2.7
django-click==2.3.0      
django-crispy-forms==1.12.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-pg-copy==0.4.0
django-storages==1.11.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
heroku3==5.1.4
idna==3.2
jmespath==0.10.0
pep517==0.12.0
Pillow==8.3.2
postgres==3.0.0
postgres.client==0.4.6
psycopg2==2.9.1
psycopg2-binary==2.9.1
psycopg2-pool==1.1
PyOpenGL==3.1.5
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-decouple==3.4
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.26.0
s3transfer==0.5.0
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
tomli==1.2.2
urllib3==1.26.6
whitenoise==5.3.0
```

Comment: can you post the requirements.txt or pipfile here??

Comment: you can make python-dateutil without any version and let pip chose

Answer (score 0):

```
asgiref==3.4.1
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3   
python-dateutil 
boto3==1.18.39
botocore==1.21.39        
certifi==2021.5.30       
charset-normalizer==2.0.4
click==8.0.1
colorama==0.4.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0   
Django==3.2.7
django-click==2.3.0      
django-crispy-forms==1.12.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-pg-copy==0.4.0
django-storages==1.11.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
heroku3==5.1.4
idna==3.2
jmespath==0.10.0
pep517==0.12.0
Pillow==8.3.2
postgres==3.0.0
postgres.client==0.4.6
psycopg2==2.9.1
psycopg2-binary==2.9.1
psycopg2-pool==1.1
PyOpenGL==3.1.5
python-decouple==3.4
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.26.0
s3transfer==0.5.0
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
tomli==1.2.2
urllib3==1.26.6
whitenoise==5.3.0
```

unversion python-dateutil
if not working visit https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/#history
and do the following try many tries and every time deploy to heroku

1. got requirements.txt and change to python-dateutil==2.5.1 if not working try lower version
2. change Heroku version to be heroku3==3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

If everything is fine in the previous deployment, you can log in to Heroku `https://dashboard.heroku.com/` & open the console of your application & get the currently installed libraries.

In case if you are not sure how to do it, `Run console` button will be available in `more` button on the right side top of your application. Then type `bash` & hit enter, bash console will be opened.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error, conflicting dependencies of the some packages, what I have done, that have fixed the problem is by removing the version number of conflicting packages, this allowed the alternative versions of the conflicting packages to be used.
example I used `requests`, instead of `requests==2.26.0`